# Run method with no active connection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I would like to create an expiration system for my website, where a user pays for a certain period of time, then their account expires. What I need is a way of making them expire. I was thinking to have a method that would run once daily and disable any user that is past the expiration date, but I don't know how to implement that, because all that I have done so far relies on a person connecting. this code should be independent from somebody visiting the site.

Edit:

Thanks for all of the ideas.

I thought to mention, I can not complete all of the task with just a job on the SQL server. I would need to move and modify files as well.

Something like this:

```
public void checkExpire()
{
    // much more code to check the expiration goes here

    if (DateTime.Now == expiration)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        user.IsApproved = false;
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
        File.Move(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "logs\\" + user.UserName + ".xml", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "logs\\disabled\\" + user.UserName + ".xml");
        File.Move(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "reps\\" + user.UserName + ".xml", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "reps\\disabled\\" + user.UserName + ".xml");
        email mail = new email("", true);
        mail.sendMail(user.UserName, "Dear user, \n\nYour account has been disabled. None of your data has been lost.\nIf you believe this was a mistake please contact the administrator", "Account Disabled");
        Response.Redirect("/Restricted/Members.aspx");
    }
}
```

I was looking at Quartz.net, would that allow me to do that?

Solved:

Thanks to Chris Marisic, who recommended Quartz.net. It allowed me to start a custom event at any interval that I wanted. for asp net, I created a button that only admin could see, that would start the event. Tutorial #3 on the quartz website was mainly what I used.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? When the account is created can't you just store the timestamp when the account was renewed the last time somewhere? And maybe with an associated account type that defines how long the account should be active?

Comment: I am using plain old forms authentication, so some things are stored in an xml file, in the xml file i would store the timestamp when it expires.

Comment: But can't you just store the timestamp when it was renewed instead? Then you can have a separate "rule" that decide if the account is old or not. And why not storing it in a database? You could create a separate database table for this information if you can't fit it somewhere.

Comment: That was a thought of mine, but the entire website is built on that series of xml files, and moving that to a database would take a MAJOR overhaul that we dont have the time to do. Anyways, it looks like Quartz.net is what I am looking for, but I am still working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question revolves around basic task scheduling which is a nontrivial task to implement.

I would recommend taking a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or the Sql Server Job Agent to acheive a system similar to the suggestions from @Nicklamont.

Comment: Quartz.net was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction Adam! Getting comments like these are why I take the time to answer questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a table in your DB for this that has username, active, expiration date columns. Along with authenticating the user, check that their account is still active with this table.

In the method you speak that you would run once daily. Check for all accounts that have expiration date of that day, and set active field to false.

Hope that gives ya some ideas, GL

Answer (score 1):

Create an SQL job in your database. Run it every night.
You can select, update or delete all bad users you want.
It is independent of C# code, and it is quite fast because it will run on SQL server.

[How to: Create a Transact-SQL Job Step (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Write a console application to do the checking.  If you have access to the server's scheduled tasks, add it to run however often you like.  If you don't know how to create a console app, here is an MSDN tutorial :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx